# <Unity> I want to add font material at the dropdown(TMP)'s template item label

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, fonts, dropdown, textmeshpro

I use a translator, the sentence can be wrong.

I want to add font material at the dropdown(TMP)'s template item label.
using dropdown(TMP), I needed a template with glowing text.
so I made font material.
works fine at dropdown(TMP)'s "Lable".
However, strangely it doesn't work with template item Label.

I attempted adding font material. and I expected template's font is shine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: The material name has to contain the according font asset name and use the according Font Atlas!

---

See [TextMeshPro - UI Text GameObjects - Font](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/TMPObjectUIText.html#font)

> **Material Preset**
>
> Choose a material for your font.
>
> Each font Asset has a default material, but you can also create customized materials for it.
>
> This preset list includes all materials **whose names contain the font Asset's name, and use the corresponding font atlas texture**.

---

So assuming you are using the default `LiberationSans SDF` try to name your material

```
LiberationSans SDF - Start2_Font
```

and in the `Debug Settings` section make sure to select the according `Font Atlas`

Then see if it appears in the material selection dropdown:

[image]

Either way the item will not allow you to directly edit the material (also seems odd to be but who knows) so if you need different settings for item and main label you will need to use different materials and edit via the material directly.

Comment: I solved with this!! I love you

Comment: Is it possible to change Material Presets with code?